# Seeking bare streets image of specific neighborhood?

Tags: qgis, data, infographics

For an infographic project, I would need the bare layout of the streets of a specific neighborhood. What I mean is just the streets "lines", without any name, color or symbol, really just the streets, on a transparent background if possible.

Is this something QGIS could do for me?

Comment: That's not really a GIS-question, but more an opendata-question. Depending on where you live, overpassturbo could be helpful.

Comment: or search http://download.geofabrik.de/, or there are some plugins around helping you download osm-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the Plugin "QuickOSM" via Plugins -> Install Plugins

In QuickOSM add in the field for key: "highway", leave the value empty and specify your location in the last field.

This will add several layers to your map, deactivate the ones you don't neede and you'll end up with what you asked for :)